# Automatically removing linebreaks in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

Often I find that I copy text from a gedit (linux) text editor document into a word processor like LibreOffice Writer.  Of course I have hard linebreaks coded into the text.

How can I do a search and replace to reflow the text in LibreOffice Writer?  In other words, I need the linebreaks removed.

**Edit:**  Since it was suggested, I will add that I did tick `regular expressions` and being an old programmer I did use `\n` just in case it has any meaning for LibreOffice.  The search key was not found when I opted for the find-and-replace.

Comment: May I ask what LibreOffice version do you use? With version 4.0 I also got the error "search key not found" [where it is working with version 3.6](http://superuser.com/questions/625093/how-to-convert-text-to-numbers-for-all-cells-in-a-spreadsheet/625152#625152).

Comment: AutoCorrect has a setting that will remove the new lines that I paste in from Emacs (they become paragraph breaks in Writer): https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Removing_Line_Breaks

Answer (score 11):

1. In the *Edit* > *Find and Replace* dialog, tick "Use regular expressions", put "\n" in the 'search for' box, nothing in the replace with box, click *Replace all*. This removes line breaks that you can insert with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (manual **line breaks**). Here's a link to [LibreOffice documentation on regular expressions](http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions).
2. LibreOffice Writer can't replace **paragraph breaks** by default. Use the [AltSearch](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/AltSearch) add-on for OpenOffice, as it also works with LibreOffice.
3. To do the paste-and-remove-linebreaks automatically, you can try recording a macro (help.libreoffice.org/Common/Macro), just paste and perform the replace and have LibreOffice record them in a macro.

Comment: I did think of using `\n` and I get "search key not found" when I search for `\n`.

Comment: This means you have no **line breaks** in the document. Use (2) to replace **paragraph breaks**.

Comment: In my case, using Find and Replace with regular expressions, and then searching for \n  gives no matches, but  searching for [:cntrl:] (a nonprinting character according [1]) gives me matches.

Not sure what character is matching [:cntrl:], maybe is not a line break.

[1] https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/02100001.html

Comment: Ok, after some investigation, I improve my previous comment: 

If search for \n don't work because there is other non printable character you can also search for [:cntrl:]  which finds ASCII non printable charcters (codes from  000 to 037 and 177 ) that means backspace, carriage return, etc ...

[1] https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/shared/01/02100001.html
[2] https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html
[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 3):

The answer you are looking for is to do find and replace, find $ and then replace with 1 blank space

Answer (score 2):

Realising that `\n` in the search and `\n` in the replacement part mean different things is helpful to know.

`\n` in the search matches "hard returns" - what you get if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

`\n` in the replacement means "end of paragraph".

In my case, I was struggling to replace lines where the visible paragraphs were all in fact just one paragraph with blank lines encoded as two "hard returns". This became obvious by turning on visibility of non-printing characters in the View menu.

So in my case, since my paras were like this (denoting "hard return as `{ent}`" and end of para as `{eop}`):

```
Para1{ent}{ent}Para2{ent}{ent}Para3{eop}
```

So a Find all then a Replace All of:

```
\n\n
```

by

```
\n
```

(with regexp turned on), changed that to:

```
Para1{eop}Para2{eop}Para3{eop}
```

It may also help to know that you can search for an extra empty paragraph by searching for `$^` (actually, `^$`, too).

Comment: You are repeating the other answer